# Confusion regarding JDBC Driver Manager component and DriverManager class

Tags: java, jdbc

According to [this](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-introduction.htm), the 'common' Components of JDBC are:

- DriverManager
- Driver
- Connection
- Statement
- Resultset
- SQLException

However according to the Java Server Programming Java EE 6 Black Book, the 'main' components of JDBC are:

- JDBC API
- DriverManager
- JDBC test Suite
- JDBC-ODBC bridge

So basically what I have understood is that components of JDBC are the union of both the lists (mentioned by black book and tutorials point). Am I right?

The book further describes that the architecture of JDBC API consists of the following things:

- DriverManager
- Driver
- Connection
- Statement
- Prepared Statement
- Callable Statement
- Resultset
- Database metadata
- ResultSet metadata
- SQLData
- Blob
- Clob

Now, the book clearly defines "Driver Manager" and "JDBC API" as two different components of JDBC. However, it lists "DriverManager" class as a part of "JDBC API".

So what exactly are the similarities and differences between the DriverManager class of JDBC API and the Driver Manager component of JDBC?

Comment: I believe the last point is a synonym (`DriverManager` == `Driver Manager`); it's a special class that loads a provider. In Java 8 the JDBC-ODBC bridge has been removed, and the various classes under `java.sql` are all part of JDBC. Finally, are you actually trying to solve a problem here?

Comment: I have some confusion regarding JDBC.Thats a legit problem for me :)

Answer (score 0):

> So what exactly are the similarities and diffrences between the DriverManager class of JDBC API and Driver Manager component of JDBC?

No difference, it's the same thing referred to in 2 ways. Read the javadoc and the Java Tutorial (http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/) section related to JDBC to see what it does.

> Also the black book further describes that the architecture of JDBC API consists of the following things:
>
> - DriverManager
> - Driver
> - Connection
> - Statement
> - Prepared Statement
> - Callable Statement
> - Resultset
> - Database metadata
> - ResultSet metadata
> - SQLData
> - Blob
> - Clob

This is a fairly complete enumeration of the classes that JDBC consists of. 
Some of them are used all the time (DriverManager, Driver, Connection, Statement, PreparedStatement, CallableStatement, Resultset), others you will need less. 
Again look into the Javadoc and the Tutorial to see what everyone of this is doing and how you glue them togheter. Actually, I'd recommend starting with the tutorial, the javadoc is more dry and packed with info, but less explanations.

Comment: Well if they are the same thing then why are they listed as different components?

Comment: As in JDBC API and Driver manager are two different components of JDBC

Comment: @Smrita Because the JDBC API depends on the Driver Manager to provide `Connection`(s) (possibly using native code). And, the Driver Manager serves absolutely no purpose with-out the JDBC API.

Comment: @ElliottFrisch yoou are implying that there's a mechanism in JDBC which loads the drivers in an application to get connection and some of its mechanism has been implemented via DriverManager class?Is that so?

Comment: @Smrita I am not implying that, I am flat out stating it. [JDBC 4.0 Enhancements in Java SE 6](http://www.onjava.com/pub/a/onjava/2006/08/02/jjdbc-4-enhancements-in-java-se-6.html) states (in part) *Thanks to the Java SE Service Provider mechanism included in Mustang, Java developers no longer need to explicitly load JDBC drivers using code like `Class.forName()` to register a JDBC driver. The `DriverManager` class takes care of this by automatically locating a suitable driver when the `DriverManager.getConnection()` method is called.*

Comment: The question of why are listed differently can be answered by the person that makes that statement, not by us obviously.

Answer (score 0):

They are one and the same thing.  The DriverManager class is a part of the JDBC API. It manages a list of database drivers , matches connection requests from a java application with the proper database driver using communication sub protocol.

The driver manager is capable of supporting multiple concurrent databases connected to heterogenous databases.

To understand where this Driver manager lies with respect to your java application and database driver here is an image

[image]

The JDBC API provides application to DriverManager connection and the JDBC Driver API provides JDBC manager to driver connection

Source: [tutorialpoint.com](http://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/jdbc-introduction.htm)